# Easy mySQL Group By question

Tags: mysql, sql

If in a mysql table RESERVATIONS there are DATE_ARRIVAL, DATE_DEPARTED and TOTAL_EARN columns

How do I `Group By` month, all earnings in `2010`?

Comment: What if DATE_ARRIVAL belongs to one month and DATE_DEPARTED belongs to another?

Comment: @karolis it doesnt matter. It is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select monthname(DATE_ARRIVAL),sum(TOTAL_EARN) from RESERVATIONS where DATE_ARRIVAL between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31 23:59:59' group by monthname(DATE_ARRIVAL);
```

Though it kind of depends on which column you want to base your predicate (DATE_ARRIVAL or DATE_DEPARTED?)

Answer (score 0):

```
select year(DATE_ARRIVAL) year, month(DATE_ARRIVAL) month, sum(TOTAL_EARN)
from RESERVATIONS 
group by year, month
order by year, month
```